# LingPipe dictionary size

Tags: java, nlp

I have created a test program based on the LingPipe DictionaryChunker example.  I am reading in dictionary values into the MapDictionary from a file.  When the file exceeds 100,000 entries the parser startes to return garbage:

for 10k rows (tail -10000 nameList.txt > shortNameList.txt)

TEXT=now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country Zoe Rogers now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country

Chunker. All matches=false Case sensitive=false
     phrase=|Zoe Rogers| start=69 end=79 type= PLAYER  score=1.0

for 100k rows (tail -100000 nameList.txt > shortNameList.txt)

TEXT=now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country Zoe Rogers now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country

Chunker. All matches=false Case sensitive=false
     phrase=|now is the time for all good men| start=0 end=32 type= PLAYER  score=1.0
     phrase=|to come to the aid of their country| start=33 end=68 type= PLAYER  score=1.0
     phrase=|Zoe Rogers now is the time for all| start=69 end=103 type= PLAYER  score=1.0
     phrase=|good men to come to the aid of| start=104 end=134 type= PLAYER  score=1.0

is there a better option for creating the MapDictionary?

I have twiddled the memory constraints on the VM, and that does not seem to help.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

turns out that allowing any of the values in the MapDictionary to be null breaks the chunker.  After removing any lines with blank values, the chunker works fine.